# Why doesn't this html/css work in ie?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I am just trying to center a div on the page.  It works in chrome but in i.e. the div is still on the left:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="margin:0 auto; width:200px;">
       test
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything I've read has said that to center a block element, simply add `margin:0 auto` and specify a width, so I don't know why this isn't working.

I am testing on IE 7.0.5730

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your HTML snippet does not have a `DOCTYPE`, [so IE is defaulting to quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

Using the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="margin:0 auto; width:200px;">
       test
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

another method would be to do this in your css, this way it works no matter if ie is in quirksmode or not:

```
body{text-align:center;}
#container{text-align: left;}
```